# Why do we need to typecast the pointer but not the variable to char whenever we are checking the endianness?

Tags: c, embedded

Following is the code checking the endianness in a computer system.

```
bool is_little_endian()
{
    int a = 0x1;
    char *c = (char *)&a;

    if(*c == a)
    {   
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But we can do the same with a variable and typecasting the `int` to `char` as below. Is there any issue with the below code?

```
bool is_little_endian()
{
    int a = 0x1;
    char c = (char) a;

    if(c == a)
    {   
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The second one will always return true, regardless of the endianess.

Comment: You could as well implement this as a compile-time calculation with an evil little macro: `#define is_little_endian() ((bool)*(char*)&(short){1})`. That is, from right to left: create a compound literal of a single short initialized to value 1. Access its address through a character pointer and de-reference the lowest byte. If 1 then little endian. Cast to bool for cosmetic purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the way you're handling returns is a bit clumsy. You can simply write:

```
bool is_little_endian()
{
    int a = 0x1;
    char *c = (char *)&a;

    return (*c == a);
}
```

The difference is that the second will always be true. The first function looks at the *first* byte in the `int` and promotes it to an `int` to compare it to `0x1`.

Comment: `return *c;` would do

Comment: In which case: `return *(char *)&a;`

Answer (score 2):

The second version of `is_little_endian` returns `true` regardless of endianess.

---

> C23 §6.3.1.3 ¶1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

Since `a` contains the value one, and since one can be represented by a `char`, `char c = a;` initializes `c` with the value one.

The subsequent `c == a` will therefore check if one equals one, and will always be true.

So the second version of `is_little_endian` will always return `true`.

Answer (score -3):

In *most* computer architectures, Random Access Memory, is implemented as an array of 8-bit (byte) addressable cells.  Such Addresses start at a given base, and increment to the end of memory.  Types other than bytes, such as half-words (2 bytes), words ( 4 bytes ), double words ( 8 bytes ), are constructed by occupying 2, 4, and 8 contiguous bytes.

A half-word with a value of `0x102` at address `0x3000`, might look like:

```
[0x3000]   02
[0x3001]   01
```

or, it might look like:

```
[0x3000]   01
[0x3001]   02
```

The choice of layout is colloquially called `endian`-ness; little vs big respectively.   The name has something to do with Gullivers Travels, not colonialism.

The first program you showed uses address equivalence, to re-interpret some storage location as both a char (byte) and an int (usually half or word).
If I store 1 to an int ( assuming word sized int ), it is either:

```
[0x3000]   00
[0x3001]   00
[0x3002]   00
[0x3003]   01
```

or:

```
[0x3000]   01
[0x3001]   00
[0x3002]   00
[0x3003]   00
```

Since the address of a (&a) is then re-interpreted as a character (byte), checking the value against `01` should reveal the layout of the underlying architecture.

Unfortunately, recent versions of *C* are no longer valid for this sort of determination.   Attempting to build and run such a program could do anything from producing the correct answer to launching global nuclear war, if the pundits are to be taken seriously.

For modern *C*, you need to rewrite such things in assembly language for enhanced portability.

Comment: What specific UB (launching global nuclear war) do you see in OP's code?  I see none so far.  `char *c = (char *)&a;` is OK.

Comment: "For modern C, you need to rewrite such things in assembly language for enhanced portability." --> C24 may provide endian macros `__STDC_ENDIAN_BIG__`,  `__STDC_ENDIAN_LITTLE__`, `__STDC_ENDIAN_NATIVE__`,